# NUnit keeping static data across tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a static class that I'm using to hold my test data.  When I reference this in my NUnit tests, any changes I make are persisted across tests.

For example, I have this code in my test:

```
OrderDto orderDto = SampleData.OrderDto;
OrderDetailDto orderDetailDto = SampleData.OrderDetailDto;
orderDto.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetailDto);
```

And sample data is something like this:

```
public static class SampleData {
    public static OrderDto OrderDto = new OrderDto { LastName = "Smith", CreatedById = 5, CreatedByDisplayName = "Smith2" };
}
```

The first time I run it, orderDto has 0 OrderDetails.  The second time it has 1, then 2, etc.  I thought between NUnit tests, nothing was persisted.  Does it cache static properties?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is up to **you** to make sure the data is not persisted across unit tests. When executed, a unit test assembly behaves just like a normal assembly, so any statics you initialize stay that way for the duration of the test.

Most unit test frameworks provide a way to inititalise and clean up your state before and after test. In NUnit, the way to do that is to have a method with `[SetUp]` attribute. This method gets executed before each test.

The easiest way to achieve what I think you want to achieve is to initialise a member field in `TestSetup` and use that between different tests. Note that we don't use a static member here, which means we don't have to clean it up after the test.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests {

  OrderDto OrderDto;
  OrderDetailDto;
  [SetUp]
  public void Setup() {
    _OrderDto = new OrderDto { LastName = "Smith", CreatedById = 5, CreatedByDisplayName = "Smith2" };
    _OrderDetailDto = new OrderDetailDto {/*Sample data*/};
  }

  [Test]
  public void TestOrderDetailIsAddedToOrder() {
    orderDto.OrderDetails.Add(_OrderDetailDto);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Tests **should** be isolated, but that doesn't mean they are automatically.

NUnit will run a method of the TestFixture tagged with `[SetUp]` before each test and `[TearDown]` afterwards. You can use this and the other [NUnit attributes](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=attributes&r=2.5.10) to set up your fixture.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question with a bit more fiddling.  Still not sure why it was updating the object, but if I change the static class to this, it works:

```
public static class SampleData {
    public static OrderDto OrderDto {
        get { return new OrderDto { LastName = "Smith", CreatedById = 5, CreatedByDisplayName = "Smith2" }; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was updating the static object because there was one instance and that's what your tests did. Unit tests are just like normal code; if they update a static field then the field gets updated. Now you're returning a new instance each time this method is called, which means that changes only affect the current instance.